# Calculate duration from Times stored as Char(4)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008, difference

I am trying to calculate the duration of a service where the times in the table are stored as Char(4) HHMM.  For example, the start time is 1402, which would be 14:02, and the end time is 1536, which would be 15:36.

I need it to return a duration of 94 minutes.  When I tried to just convert to numeric and subtract I get 134.  I have tried to convert to time, but every example I have tried gives me a conversion type message.

Comment: You have 3 excellent answers.  I have +1's for each.  I'm curious to see how this one goes.  I do prefer one of the solutions but I'll keep my opinion to myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the value to a `time`, and then use `DATEDIFF`:

```sql
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(time,STUFF(StartTime,3,0,':')),CONVERT(time,STUFF(EndTime,3,0,':')))
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string functions and arithmetics:

```
select t.*,
    (left(starttime, 2) * 60 + right(starttime, 2) - left(endtime, 2) * 60 - left(endtime)) / 60 minutes_diff
from mytable t
```

This converts the strings to a number of seconds, substracts the values, then converts back to minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the difference to minutes and then add that back to a zero time:

```
select convert(time,
               dateadd(minute,
                       (((et / 100) * 60) + (et % 60)) -  (((st / 100) * 60) + (st % 60)),
                       0)
              )
from (values (1402, 1536)) v(st, et);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf7b14da68811f43d3d5e7e8633e3269) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the answers, but I found my answer!

```
DateDiff(Minute, try_cast(substring(c.start_time, 1, 2) + ':' + substring(start_time, 3, 2) as time), 
                try_cast(substring(stop_time, 1, 2) + ':' + substring(c.stop_time, 3, 2) as time))
```

Comment: Of course now we'll never know!  This most resembles @Larnu's answer tho

Answer (score 0):

Task: given two parametes as char(4)

- 1402, 1536     in format HHMM
- Return duration in minutes: 15*60+36 - 14*60+02  => 94

Solution:

SELECT (CAST(SUBSTRING('1536',1,2) AS int)*60 + CAST(SUBSTRING('1536',3,2) AS int))
- (CAST(SUBSTRING('1402',1,2) AS int)*60 + CAST(SUBSTRING('1402',3,2) AS int));